# Why am I unable to edit the values in this hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I'm trying to create a new hash called `$player[:abil_mods]` which is based on my `$player[:abils]` hash. It should take each value, subtract 10, divide by 2, and assign it to an identical key in the new hash. However, it doesn't seem to be editing the values in `$player[:abil_mods]`.

My code:

```
$player = {
  abils: {str: 20, con: 20, dex: 14, wis: 12, int: 8, cha: 8},
  abil_mods: {}
}

$player[:abil_mods] = $player[:abils].each { |abil, pts| ((pts - 10) / 2).floor }
```

should create the following `$player[:abil_mods]` hash:

```
abil_mods: {str: 5, con: 5, dex: 2, wis: 1, int: -1, cha: -1}
```

but it is instead creating:

```
abil_mods: {str: 20, con: 20, dex: 14, wis: 12, int: 8, cha: 8}
```

Comment: Odds are really good that using a global `$player` is not the right thing to do. The vast majority of the time people use globals when they don't understand variable scoping because a global will step around scope issues, but it opens a big hole for bugs and problems later in your code. I'd recommend spending more time getting to understand why, and why not, you should use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the line

```
$player[:abil_mods] = $player[:abils].each { |abil, pts| ((pts - 10) / 2).floor }
```

you are assigning the return value of the method `Hash#each` that is `self` to the the Hash `$player` at key `:abil_mods`. In your case the Hash is referenced by `$player[:abils]`.

You could use `Enumerable#map` which returns an array that can be easily converted to a hash:

```
$player[:abil_mods] = $player[:abils].map { |k, pts| [k,  ((pts - 10) / 2).floor] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `#each` returns the hash it's operating on. (At least that's how it works on arrays...) It's more about *doing something with each entry* than about returning the results of that something.

You might try instead:

```
$player[:abil_mods] = $player[:abils].transform_values { |pts| ((pts - 10) / 2).floor }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map` instead of `each` in this line:

```
$player[:abil_mods] = $player[:abils].map { |abil, pts| ((pts - 10) / 2).floor }
```

`each` iterates over the array but return the original array. Whereas `map` returns the new values.

Btw: Using global variables (the one with the `$`) is almost every time a bad idea. Using instance of local variables is preferred.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Why is using global variables a bad idea? I've only ever heard that it's not very Ruby to use them.

Comment: The problem with global variables is that, not only are they visible anywhere in the code for a program, they can also be changed from anywhere in the application. This can make tracking bugs difficult. I would argue that such a global variable and global state is a code smell.